# Display two td's in seperate line

Tags: html, vue.js

I have two td's under one tr. How can i show the 2nd td in next line.Currently its displaying in same line.I would have to loop the users object and its content multiple times.

```
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Status</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="index">
     <td>
        {{ user.id}}
     </td>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tbody>
              <tr v-for="(info,index) in user.demographic" :key="index">
                 <td>
                    {{info.name}}
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    {{info.address}}
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Use another `tr` for new line. Though I don't understand how you want them to display. And maybe you are looking for rowspan and colspan